# Aggregating last n days in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to build a query in MongoDb (to be run with pymongo) to get a sum by groups for the last 30 days. I'm really struggling to combine both aggregate function and date differences. Tne SQL equivalent of the query would be:

```sql
SELECT item, sum(volume) from table
where date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, now())
group by item
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple, first you want to match the matching documents by their date field and then use `$group` to calculate the sum.

First what we need for the code:

```
import pymongo
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("connection url")
collection = connection["db_name"]['collection_name']
```

Main Aggregation:

```
thirty_days_ago = date.today() - timedelta(days=30)
results = list(collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "date": {"$gt": thirty_days_ago }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "item",
            "sum": {"$sum": "$volume"}
        }
    }
]))
```

I had to guess some of the fields names as you did not provide a schema but you should be able to easily adapt it to your needs.

Comment: This worked after a minor correction: `n_days_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=n_days)`. Thanks!